# Use symlink to change extension format of subtitles

Tags: shell, find, symlink

I am trying to write a shell command (Linux) that will look for all the subtitles that are ending to NAME.el.srt and make a symlink of them in format NAME.srt (removing .el from it).

Using:

`/usr/bin/find /volume1/public/test -follow -type f \( -iname "*.el.srt" \)`

Gives me the following Results:

`/volume1/public/test/Arrow - S01E04.el.srt`

`/volume1/public/test/Arrow - S01E01.el.srt`

`/volume1/public/test/Arrow - S01E02.el.srt`

`/volume1/public/test/Arrow - S01E03.el.srt`

I don't want to rename them. I just want to create a symlink in the same folder as the originals.

I thought that was going to be an easy shot... but after 4 hours I am just looking for someone more experienced to help me out :)
Finally I found it:

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b");

for j in $(find /volume1/video -follow -type d -name "*");
do
cd $j;
for i in $(find $j -name "*.el.srt" -maxdepth 1 -exec basename {} \;);  
do 
  rname=$(echo "$i" | sed -e 's/\.el\.srt/\.srt/g'); 
  ln -s "$i" "$rname";
done
done
```

Thank you iamuser for pointing me to the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a simple for loop to do that.

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b");
for i in $(find . -name "*.el.srt"); 
do 
  rname=$(echo "$i" | sed -e 's/\.el\.srt/\.srt/g'); 
  ln -s "$i" "$rname";
done
```

It loops over all the files that ends with `.el.srt` in the current directory. For each file, it creates a temporary variable `rname` which has the extension `.srt` without the `.el` part. Then it does a symlink with `ln -s`.

Comment: It gives me the following errors and creates some crazy symlinks... 'ln: ./Arrow: File exists
ln: -: File exists
ln: ./Arrow: File exists
ln: -: File exists
ln: ./Arrow: File exists
ln: -: File exists'

Comment: Edited my answer. You need `IFS`.

Comment: Yes, now it works. Is it possible to use it with the find command (as I mentioned above) so as to make a cron that will run once a day? I think that with your solution I have to run separately in each folder (and I have MANY :O)

Comment: I think you can run the same script by replacing the dot `.` with `/Volume1/public/test`. It should work as well.

Comment: Well, it works BUT the symlink instead of being like that "Arrow1.srt -> Arrow1.el.srt" it is being like "Arrow1.srt -> volume1/public/test/Arrow1.el.srt" which cannot be found by the player. If the symlink was just using the name and not the path then it was going to work just fine!